# How to collect all data from first column in table into array?

Tags: netbeans

I using netbeans 8.
I need to loop to collect all employee ID from first column of jtable and store those IDs into an arraylist.

```
  if (jTabledetail.getRowCount() > 0) {
        String ecode = "";

        int ishasRow = jTabledetail.getRowCount();// total 1 row

        for (int r = 0; r <= ishasRow; r++) {// loop twice. First loop is gone, return to second loop or final loop for 1 row exists giving error bellow.
            ecode = jTabledetail.getValueAt(r, 0).toString();
            arrempcode.add(ecode);
        }

    }
```

## I also tried changing to ==>> for (int r = 0; r < ishasRow; r++)  but not worked.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
             at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
             at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
             at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
```

I don't understand the error. I known that the error comes from loop expression. I am not sure for this error.

Now my jtable named "jTabledetail" has 1 row exists.

Do I need to change something for this case of error? I am not sure that the loop expression is wrong.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) TableName.getModel();
```

Get the row count of the table

```
int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
```

Declare ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Traversing table and adding values into arraylist

```
for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++){
        if(j==0){
            list.add(tableModel.getValueAt(i,j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anil Chuarasiya, it is very useful. But can I use int[] list = tableModel.getSelectedRowcount() ?

Comment: Because, her I can find for tableModel.getSelectedRowCount().

Comment: Sorry! I did not understand your question..  Will you explain it?